# Is << a double caret?

Tags: symbols

I understand that in the Ruby language this **<<** symbol is referred to as a shovel operator. I hear people refer to it as a double caret, so I googled it as I wanted to know what the meaning was. It turns out that it is not a caret after all? This symbol **^** is what is referred to as a caret. So is calling this **<<** a double caret acceptable terminology in the programming community or is it wrong?

Tried google to get some clarity, but it looks like this is niche for some reason!

Comment: I'd call it the left-shift operator, never heard of "double caret"

Comment: Can you [edit] and provide links to places where it's referred to?

Comment: did not see it referred to online, during live coding sessions people referred to it as a double caret. So knowing they were referring to << I wanted to know what it meant. It is whilst researching the name for the less than sign < that I read that it is not called a caret. ^ symbol is a caret. I guess that they were then misnaming the < symbol.